# magnitude of unknown force on wall bracket question

Tags: geometry, vectors, physics

I'm really stuck with part b of this question, even where to start. I think I keep over complicating it. If anyone could help that'd be amazing!

[image]

Comment: You should post the picture with the question

Comment: Did the link not work? I tried to post it with the question but it converted to an external link

Comment: the link works however generally questions/answers that depend on links are looked down on as the link can go dead.

Comment: Sorry! I just started using this site so it will only let me post images a links, until I earn a higher reputation apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  resolve $F_2$ and $F_3$ into $x$ and $y$ components.  Subtract them from the given resultant vector.  The result is $F_1$ in components.  Now change that to magnitude and compute $\theta$.

Comment: So ive got 

f2= 40i-69.3j
f3=76.6i+64.3j
fr= 0i-100j

so f1= 0i-100j - 40i-69.3j - 76.6i+64.3
f1= -116.6i-95j

Calculated the magnitude to be approximately 150.3

and using tan^-1(116.6/95) found theta to be approximately 50.8.

So theta is 50.8 degrees from the y axis and f1 is approximately 150.3 N